# Office Apps, how send copy of doc file with ajax to C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, office-app

hello i have this problem:

I have a addins for office(word);

I want to send a copy of current file (.docx) to C# controller, i have this code now, at this stage of the code i get a array of chars or somethis in the "yourfile", how ca i get a .docx file?

**JavaScript**

```
function sendFile() {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync("compressed",
        { sliceSize: 100000 },
        function (result) {

            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                var myFile = result.value;
                var state = {
                    file: myFile,
                    counter: 0,
                    sliceCount: myFile.sliceCount
                };

                getSlice(state);

            }
        });
            }

function getSlice(state) {

    state.file.getSliceAsync(state.counter, function (result) {
        if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

            sendSlice(result.value, state);
        }

    });
}

 function myEncodeBase64(str) 

{
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function (match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
    }

 function sendSlice(slice, state) {
        var data = slice.data;

        if (data) {

           var fileData = myEncodeBase64(data);
           var _url = '../../api/file';

            useAjax(_url, 'Post', JSON.stringify(fileData), _contentType).done(function (data) {
                writeData(data);
                app.showNotification("Translation was successfully done!");
            });
        }

    }
```

And the C# **CONTROLLER**:

```
    public static string filemame = @"c:\yourfile";

    [Route("file")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void getFile([FromBody] string data)
    {

        Base64ToFile(data,filemame);

    }

 public static void Base64ToFile(string base64String, string filename)
        {


            byte[] fileByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            // Instantiate FileStream to create a new file
            System.IO.FileStream writeFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
            // Write converted base64String to newly created file
            writeFileStream.Write(fileByteArray, 0, fileByteArray.Length);
            // Clean up / disposal
            writeFileStream.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I'm adding the answer here nonetheless, in case someone else will need it at some later date.

Instead of using myEncodeBase64 you should use

```
var fileData = OSF.OUtil.encodeBase64(data);
```

It's a function that is part of the Office API, so you don't have to define anything else.

Comment: Exactly what was needed. I had no idea this existed until I saw your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can also use the javascript builtin encode to Base64: btoa. That makes var fileData = btoa(data);

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling to construct a correct pptx serverside. Eventually this is what I came up with.

**Javascript**

```
function sendSlice(slice, state) {
    var data = slice.data;
    if (data) {
        var isLastSlice = state.counter >= (state.sliceCount -1);
        var ajaxData = {
            isLastSlice: isLastSlice,
            counter: state.counter,
            documentData: btoa(data)
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Constructpptx", method: "POST", data: ajaxData, success: function (result) {
                state.counter++;
                if (isLastSlice) {
                   closeFile(state);
                }
                else {
                    getSlice(state);
                }

            }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And as an API backend I use this
**C# ApiController**

```
public class ConstructpptxController : ApiController
{
    public static List<byte> Document { get; set; } = new List<byte>();

    public string Post([FromBody]ConstructpptxPayload payload)
    {
        if (payload.counter == 0)
            Document.Clear();

        var payloadData = Convert.FromBase64String(payload.documentData);
        var pptBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payloadData).Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
        Document.AddRange(pptBytes);
        if(payload.isLastSlice)
        {
            var path = @"C:/Some/Local/Path/Presentation.pptx";                
            var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fileStream.Write(Document.ToArray(), 0, Document.Count());
            fileStream.Close();

            Document.Clear();
        }
        return $"Counter: {payload.counter}, isLast: {payload.isLastSlice}, docLength: {Document.Count}";
    }
} 

public class ConstructpptxPayload
{
    public bool isLastSlice { get; set; }
    public int counter { get; set; }
    public string documentData { get; set; }
}
```

**Please note:** only use this example as a quick starting point, as you don't want to save the bytes in a *static List Document*. Instead you want to make your webserver stateless.